# Query sum over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, spree

I need help with a difficult query. This has to do with the complex way coupons are implemented in Spree Commerce platform.

I simply need the total amount of outstanding coupons.

The tables are:

preferences

```
id | value  | key
---+---------------------------------------------
1  | 25     | spree/calculator/flat_rate/amount/5
```

calculators

```
id  | calculable_id | calculable_type
----+---------------+-----------------
5   | 3             | promotion_action
```

promotion_actions

```
id  | activator_id  
----+-------------
3   | 2
```

activators

```
id | expires_at | usage_limit 
---+------------+------------
2  | 2013-12-01 | 4
```

adjustments

```
originator_type  | originator_id | amount
-----------------+---------------+-------
promotion_action | 3             | -25
```

The last number in preferences.key corresponds to the id of the calculator.

First I need the total of preferences.amount, multiplied by activators.usage_limit (unless activators.expires_at < today), where the preferences.key LIKE '%calculator/flat_rate%'.

The result should be this amount minus the total sum of the corresponding adjustments.amount

I got as far as

```
select 
 (select sum(value) from spree_preferences 
   where `key` like "%calculator/flat_rate%") 
 + 
 (select sum(amount) from spree_adjustments 
   where originator_type = 'promotion_action') as total;
```

,but this doesn't take into account the expires_at and usage_limit.

For updated spree, the answer is as below:

`select sum(subAggregate.outstanding)
from
    (
    select (subDetail.value * subDetail.multiplier) + subDetail.adjustmentAmount as outstanding
    from
        (
        select  p.value,
                case
                    when a.expires_at > curDate() then a.usage_limit
                    else 1
                end as multiplier ,
                ifNull(adj.amount,0) as adjustmentAmount
        from    spree_preferences p
                left outer join spree_calculators c
                    on replace(p.key,'spree/calculator/flat_rate/amount/','') = c.id
                left outer join spree_promotion_actions pa
                    on c.calculable_id = pa.id
                    and c.calculable_type = 'Spree::PromotionAction'
                left outer join spree_promotions a
                    on pa.promotion_id = a.id
                left outer join spree_adjustments adj
                    on pa.id = adj.source_id
                    and pa.type = 'Spree::PromotionAction'
        ) subDetail
    ) subAggregate`

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me" site. Show us the part of your code that is not working and we might help.

Comment: I've shown how far I've got. I wouldn't have posted this super long question if I had any clue of how to solve this. I can completely understand if you don't want to help since the query is just too complex.

Comment: "The last number in preferences.key corresponds to the id of the calculator."  Whoever did this should be fired.

Comment: I'm still not clear how the tables are related. Can you provide information about you **Primary** and **Foreign keys**?  Also please post the expected result of your query based on your sample data.

Comment: `calculators.calculable_id` corresponds to *what*? `adjustments.originator_id` corresponds to *what*? The naming doesn't give many hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(subAggregate.outstanding)
from
    (
    select (subDetail.value * subDetail.multiplier) + subDetail.adjustmentAmount as outstanding
    from
        (
        select  p.value,
                case
                    when a.expires_at > curDate() then a.usage_limit
                    else 1
                end as multiplier ,
                ifNull(adj.amount,0) as adjustmentAmount
        from    preferences p
                left outer join calculators c
                    on replace(p.key,'spree/calculator/flat_rate/amount/','') = c.id
                left outer join promotion_actions pa
                    on c.calculabel_id = pa.id
                    and c.calculable_type = 'promotion_action'
                left outer join activators a
                    on pa.activator_id = a.id
                left outer join adjustments adj
                    on pa.id = adj.originator_id
                    and pa.originator_type = 'promotion_action'
        ) subDetail
    ) subAggregate
```